# Как создать tron кошелек на python?

Tags: python, blockchain, криптография, tron

Всем привет я создаю веб кошелек для блокчейна трон, я бы хотел узнать, есть ли какой то способ для создания трон кошелька на питоне?
документацию tronpy почитал, к сожалению ответа не нашел.
заранее благодарю

Answer (score 0):

для создания tron кошелька вам нужно установить tronpy `pip install tronpy`
за создание кошелька отвечает команда: `wallet = client.generate_address()`
а что бы узнать данные кошелька мы просто используем команду `print()`

```
    print("Wallet address:  %s" % wallet['base58check_address'])
    print("Private Key:  %s" % wallet['private_key'])
```

полностью готовый код вы можете просмотреть ниже:

```
from tronpy import Tron

# подключаемся к блокчейну трон
client = Tron()

# создаем кошелек и печатаем его данные
def create_wallet(): 
    wallet = client.generate_address()
    print("Wallet address:  %s" % wallet['base58check_address'])
    print("Private Key:  %s" % wallet['private_key'])
```